# Fiducial design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-assembly

I'm a bit confused about the correct fiducial design. I've been reading about pick and place machines, and some suggest that fiducials should be round while others say they should be a cross. Also, sometimes I read that it should have paste on top and sometimes not.

So what is a standard design for such a fiducial? This was my approach until I read about it:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check this link for guidelines:
http://www.accutroninc.com/pdf/download/fiducial.pdf

1mm diameter, round, with 2mm diameter of solder mask removed is the IPC guideline.

Answer (score 7):

There's a bit more about it at http://denatechnologies.com/capabilities/pcb-fiducial-guidelines My impression is that various manufacturers may have slightly different preferences for the ideal one, so it's probably a good idea to find out if/what your manufacturer has a its own preference/guideline... assuming you're making the design for only one mfg. Dena tech recommends the R-3R (1mm/3mm) variant.

Accutronic in the document linked [in the other answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/196085/54580) also recommends the R-3R version rather than the R-2R [IPC] one, which they still support though.

[image]

The SMEMA std can be found [here](http://www.page.be/Bestukking_Media/Feducial-markers-IPC.pdf) for example. Note that they say R-2R is the minimal design:

> The size of the clearance area shall have a radius that is **at least** twice that of the fiducial mark and shall be concentric with the center of the fiducial mark

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are excellent. In addition, it is common practice to put a feature in the solder paste layer that matches the fiducial's copper layer. This is to assist aligning the solder stencil over the PCB.